# Not understanding root of the error

Tags: shell

When I'm compiling a shell script there is this error that is being generated, 
"**No such file or directoryity.c**"

I didn't get why there is no space between directory and the name. 
I have a file named "Utlity.c", so I think the trailing part of the error message is taken from there. Please help.

Here's the content of the shell script

```
 #!/bin/sh 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib >> ~/.bashrc 
gcc MyFol/main.c MyFol/Utility.c -L /usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o SD 
gcc -c -O3 -I /usr/local/include/ ivectTmatC/tmatTrain.c ivectTmatC/Utility.c gfortran tmatTrain.o Utility.o /usr/local/lib/liblapacke.a /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a 
/usr/local/lib/librefblas.a /usr/local/lib/libgsl.a /usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.a
 -o ivectTmat 
g++ cosineKernel/cosineKernel.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o cosineKerne
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your shell script?

Comment: @Shai  #!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib >> ~/.bashrc
gcc MyFol/main.c MyFol/Utility.c -L /usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o SD
gcc -c -O3 -I /usr/local/include/ ivectTmatC/tmatTrain.c ivectTmatC/Utility.c
gfortran tmatTrain.o Utility.o /usr/local/lib/liblapacke.a /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a /usr/local/lib/librefblas.a /usr/local/lib/libgsl.a /usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.a -o ivectTmat
g++ cosineKernel/cosineKernel.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o cosineKerne

Comment: @GauravRai Can you add that into the question?

Comment: @MrLister - Shai already edited it.

Comment: Is this the entire error message? "Why there is no space" can be possible because of something printing backspace. I don't think its entire error msg.

Comment: Check the spelling in your script. The only "ity.c" I can see in there is the trailing part of "MyFol/Utility.c", so I suspect some erroneous newline / carriage return in there that got lost in the copy & paste.

Comment: I re-installed some packages that were required in the project and the problem is gone. Trying to find what changes it made, will inform asap. Thank you for the support.

Comment: I re-installed the packages, copied the script using "cp" command to another file used that in place of this script. Nothing worked. But when I wrote (not copied) a new script which was exactly the same and used that it worked.  I'm guessing that the old file was corrupt and some how a new file worked. I'm still leaving this question open as there was no satisfactory explanation.

Comment: Voting to close "Off Topic / Not reproducable / Typo".